# Is there any difference between a TV and a monitor in regard to input latency?

Tags: performance, monitor

Is there any difference between a TV and a monitor in regard to input latency (for high-speed online games such as fighting games, sports simulators, and FPS) when connected to a PS/Xbox via HDMI cable? If there is, can it realistically affect gaming performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of your output device or means, TVs were never designed with low input lag in mind.

As you can see from [this study](https://www.rtings.com/tv/tests/inputs/input-lag) TV latency varies from 15ms to 100ms and that is borderline unacceptable for a fast paced game.

In comparison pretty much every gaming monitor's selling point is 1ms, 2ms, 3ms and now even sub 1ms.