# Will playing on TV cause delays?

Tags: monitor

I would like to know if playing on a TV will cause input delays. Right now I play on a 60 Hz monitor. The TV is also 60 Hz but is a bigger screen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Latency: TV vs monitor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/326743/latency-tv-vs-monitor)

Answer (score 0):

The *refresh rate* (your 60 Hz value) doesn't define the image delay.

You'll want to compare their [*response time*](https://www.howtogeek.com/405903/what-is-a-monitors-response-time-and-why-does-it-matter/) instead. This tells you the delay to expect.

From the article liked above:

> Response time is the time it takes your monitor to shift from one
>   color to another. Usually, this is measured in terms of going from
>   black to white to black again, in terms of milliseconds. A typical LCD
>   response time is under ten milliseconds (10 ms), with some being as
>   fast as one millisecond.

However, it only matters for fast paced games, such as shooters. For games where super duper reactions don't matter (MMOs, Minecraft, etc.) it's not worth it. Fast response times cost image quality, so you should choose wisely.